# node.js- no-Kafka- Kafka broker - MessageSizeTooLarge Error

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

We are using node.js with no-kafka client. We have a file upload functionality where the file is json and then it is being read and converted to Base64 and producer is sending it to Kafka. Kafka has a message size limit configured as 6MB

Now when I upload a file of size 4.3-4.4 Mb it reaches Kafka and is processed. But when I upload a file> 4.4 Mb I get the KafkaError: MessageSizeTooLarge

Are there any configs that i need to set in Node.js or in no kafka producer/client.

In the client.js file I printed the request lenght and the messageset length in the method that produces the request 
When I print the message length for a 4.5 mb file it shows the request length as 6432489 which is > 6MB

And when I print the message length for a 4.3Mb file it shows the request length as 5838373 which is < 6MB

Where is the additional data coming from and how do I handle it.

All I need is that a file with size upto 5MB get uploaded to KAFKA.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The Base 64 encoding increases the size of the payload. so even if hte file is 5MB on base64 encoding it becomes 6.3 approx Mb.

To accomodate 5mb file we increases the kafka message limit to 7MB

Comment: Why do you need to Base64 encode the message? Can’t you just publish the JSON? I know with node-rdkafka client you can even publish with Snappy compression and make the JSON message even smaller.